# How to configure phpmyadmin with nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm trying configure nginx with phpmyadmin, but when i go to link localhost\phpmyadmin i see, error "404 not found"

In "/var/log/nginx/error.log" i see error open() "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin" failed (2: No such file or directory)

But i created link in
ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

this is my default.conf:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost;



location /phpmyadmin/ {                               
    alias   /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
} 


location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

What i doing wrong?

Anybody help me?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server, will post as answer if it works for you

Comment: i has tried to understand this instruction already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just changed my `root` directory, and deleted the phpmyadmin `location`, like so:

was: `root /var/www/html`
now: `root /usr/share/nginx/html`

deleted :

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {                     
    alias   /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```